# How to setup recurring subscription using Avangate

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, payment, recurring-billing

I'm building a membership area and i'm using avangate.com as payment system.

I just want to update the subscriber date in database with new expiration date when recurring payment has happened.

I got this ipn code from them as starting point:

```
<?php
/* Internet Payment Notification */

$pass       = "AABBCCDDEEFF";   /* pass to compute HASH */
$result     = "";               /* string for compute HASH for received data */
$return     = "";               /* string to compute HASH for return result */
$signature  = $_POST["HASH"];   /* HASH received */
$body       = "";

/* read info received */
ob_start();
while(list($key, $val) = each($_POST)){
    $$key=$val;

    /* get values */
    if($key != "HASH"){

        if(is_array($val)) $result .= ArrayExpand($val);
        else{
            $size       = strlen(StripSlashes($val));
            $result .= $size.StripSlashes($val);
        }

    }

}
$body = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush();

$date_return = date("YmdGis");

$return = strlen($_POST["IPN_PID"][0]).$_POST["IPN_PID"][0].strlen($_POST["IPN_PNAME"][0]).$_POST["IPN_PNAME"][0];
$return .= strlen($_POST["IPN_DATE"]).$_POST["IPN_DATE"].strlen($date_return).$date_return;

function ArrayExpand($array){
    $retval = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++){
        $size       = strlen(StripSlashes($array[$i]));
        $retval .= $size.StripSlashes($array[$i]);
    }

    return $retval;
}

function hmac ($key, $data){
   $b = 64; // byte length for md5
   if (strlen($key) > $b) {
       $key = pack("H*",md5($key));
   }
   $key  = str_pad($key, $b, chr(0x00));
   $ipad = str_pad('', $b, chr(0x36));
   $opad = str_pad('', $b, chr(0x5c));
   $k_ipad = $key ^ $ipad ;
   $k_opad = $key ^ $opad;
   return md5($k_opad  . pack("H*",md5($k_ipad . $data)));
}

$hash =  hmac($pass, $result); /* HASH for data received */

$body .= $result."\r\n\r\nHash: ".$hash."\r\n\r\nSignature: ".$signature."\r\n\r\nReturnSTR: ".$return;

if($hash == $signature){
    echo "Verified OK!";

    /* ePayment response */
    $result_hash =  hmac($pass, $return);
    echo "<EPAYMENT>".$date_return."|".$result_hash."</EPAYMENT>";

    /* Begin automated procedures (START YOUR CODE)*/


}else{
    /* warning email */
    mail("your_address@example.com","BAD IPN Signature", $body,"");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the LCN response, not the IPN. With the LCN there is the `EXPIRATION_DATE` field in the data array that tell us the new expiration data.

You also need to test that the petition is correct (the product, the subscription, etc), but the main part is using the LCN (License Change Notification) hook.